Maven multi module project deployment with local parent pom
I've a question regarding the use of a local parent pom, when it comes to deployment and release of artifacts which use this parent's pom.
Imagine the following multi module maven projects:
- pom.xml (Aggregator)
|
-- Submodule 1
|
--- pom.xml
|
-- Submodule 2
|
--- pom.xml
|
-- parent
|
--- pom.xml

Now, I use the parent/pom.xml as parent (with relative path!) in Submodule 1, respectively Submodule 2. Within the aggregator pom, we define both submodules.
If we now try to deploy them with mvn deploy we face the error, that the parent pom isn't available in maven central. Okay, fine. But: If I add the parent/pom.xml as a submodule to the aggregator, the deployment works. (nothing else changed)
As I really like to understand that behavior to think of possible pro's and con's, I would appreciate if someone could explain that :-)
Thank you!
I tried what I mentioned, including the parent pom.xml as submodule and not.

If the parent POM does not appear in your aggregator POM as a submodule, it will de facto not be built/deployed. So when maven wants to upload the submodules, it notices that the parent POM is missing and maven aborts.
Your solution of integrating the Parent POM as a module avoids this error. However, it is still not the way you would normally solve it.
By default, your project structure should look like this:
parent
|-- submodul-1
|-- submodul-2
|-- submodul-3

See for example: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules-4.html
